# How to calculate the close loop gain? Am I solving it in the right way?

Tags: closed-loop

The following is a question from 8.18 in  *[Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuit](https://electrovolt.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Design-of-Analog-CMOS-Integrated-Circuit-2nd-Edition-ElectroVolt.ir_.pdf)*, page 342.

Consider the circuit this following Fig, \$(\frac{W} {L})_{1-4} =\frac{50} {0.5} \$, \$|{I_D}_{1-4}| = 0.5 mA\$, \$R_2 = 3 k\Omega\$.

[image]

Calculate the closed-loop gain and output impedance.

Break the loop and add test voltage.

[image]

$$\frac{V_x -V_F} {r_{o1}} - V_F g_{m1} = -\frac{V_x} {r_{o3}}$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{V_x} {V_F} = (r_{o1} \parallel r_{o3}) (r_{o1} \parallel \frac{1} {g_{m1}})$$

$$- \frac{V_{out}} {r_{o4}} = V_x g_{m2} + \frac{V_{out}} {r_{o2}}$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{V_{out}} {V_x} = - g_{m2} (r_{o2} \parallel r_{o4})$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{V_{out}} {V_F} = \frac{V_{out}} {V_x} \frac{V_x} {V_F}  = 
- g_{m2} (r_{o1} \parallel r_{o3}) (r_{o1} \parallel \frac{1} {g_{m1}}) (r_{o2} \parallel r_{o4})$$

$$V_F = \frac{R_1} {R_1 + R_2} V_{test}$$

$$A \beta = \frac{V_{out}} {V_{test}} = - g_{m2} (r_{o1} \parallel r_{o3}) (r_{o1} \parallel \frac{1} {g_{m1}}) (r_{o2} \parallel r_{o4})  \frac{R_1} {R_1 + R_2} $$

To calculate open loop gain, we can have this circuit.

[image]

Between M1 and M3, we have
$$-\frac{V_x} {r_{o3}} = \frac{V_p} {R_1 \parallel R_2}$$
$$\frac{V_x - V_p} {r_{o1}} + (V_{in} - V_p) g_{m1} = - \frac{V_x} {r_{o3}}$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{V_x} {V_{in}} = \frac{g_{m1}} {1 / (r_{o1} \parallel r_{o3}) + \frac{R_1 \parallel R_2} {r_{o1} \parallel \frac{1} {g_{m1}}} }$$

Between M2 and M4, we have

$$- (\frac{V_{out}} {r_{o4}} + \frac{V_{out}} {R_1 + R_2}) = V_x g_{m2} + \frac{V_{out}} {r_{o2}}$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{V_{out}} {V_x} = -g_{m2} \bigr(r_{o2} \parallel r_{o4} \parallel (R_1 + R_2) \bigr)$$

$$A_{v,open} = \frac{V_{out}} {V_{in}} = \frac{V_{out}} {V_x} \frac{V_x} {V_{in}} = -g_{m2} \frac{g_{m1}} {1 / (r_{o1} \parallel r_{o3}) + \frac{R_1 \parallel R_2} {r_{o1} \parallel \frac{1} {g_{m1}}} }  \bigr(r_{o2} \parallel r_{o4} \parallel (R_1 + R_2) \bigr)$$

$$A_{v,close} = \frac{A_{v,open}} {1 + A \beta}$$

The following is what I found from internet. Is this correct?

[image]

$$A \beta = \frac{V_F} {V_t} = \frac{1} {R_2} (R_1 \parallel R_2) \frac{r_{o3}} {(R_1 \parallel R_2) + \frac{1} {g_{m1}}} g_{m2} (r_{o4} \parallel (R_1 + R_2) \parallel r_{o2}) \frac{R_1} {R_1 + R_2}$$

$$A_{v,close} = \frac{r_{o3}} {(R_1 \parallel R_2) + \frac{1} {g_{m1}}} g_{m2} \Bigr(r_{o4} \parallel (R_1 + R_2) \parallel r_{o2} \Bigr)$$

Comment: I'm wondering if you realize (by simple and quick visual inspection of the circuit) that the closed loop gain is \$1+\frac{R2}{R1}\$ <-- is this what you are aiming to achieve? I mean, trying to get a very precise formula is kind of missing the point when it comes to real life devices and their variations.

Comment: @Andyaka  I want to get better results with hand calculation

Comment: @kile - I think, for finding the loop gain you forgot the load at the node V_out.  More than that, for finding the gain under open-loop conditions you forgot that the load must be (R2+R21||rin) with rin=input resistance at the source of M1.

Comment: @Lvw Do you  mean there is resistor feedback network at node \$V_{out}\$? I don't understand what you \$((R_2 + R_1) \parallel R_{in})  \$ is? Why do we need \$R_{in}\$?

Comment: @kile - please write rin (and NOT Rin) because rin is a dynamic resistance and it is very important not to mix dynamic/differential quantities with static values. In the 2nd part of your calculations, why do you load the node Vout with (R2+R1) ? This is OK because this node is in fact loaded - however, there is another resistance across R1, is it not? And this resistance (rin) is pretty small (in contrast to the case of an opamp where the inverting input represents a very large resistance, which can be neglected).

Comment: @LvW How can you calculate  dynamic resistance \$r_{in}\$? Can you write in the answer?

Comment: @kile - the input resistance at the  source is always 1/gm (inverse transconductance)

Comment: @LvW Which transistor is it? Is it M1?

Comment: @kile - I gave this information in the 3rd comment above!

Answer (score 2):

First of all you must identify the class (configuration) to which the feedback amplifier belongs. Then proceed as in one of the examples on the texts indicated in the figure where I also show the page:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Serie-Shunt for my case. What do you think

Comment: The analysis is done after tracing the equivalent circuit for incremental signals or dynamic circuit. Did you draw it? I do not see it!

Comment: I think my analysis is  equivalent circuit for incremental signals or dynamic circuit. Where will you break the loop?

Comment: In the equivalent circuit, each active device must be replaced with its dynamic  equivalent circuit. The transistor symbol should be used only in the bias circuit. The open loop gain βA, if I'm not mistaken, does not depend on where you break the loop, i.e., it is always the same wherever you break the loop.

Comment: Honestly, I haven't checked your calculations at all. But I would advise you to study the eighth chapter on reaction again.

Comment: Could you draw the dynamic circuit?

Comment: @Franc - when you speak (write) about "open loop gain βA" - what do you mean? This is a rather important point because very often there are misunderstandings (resp. confusion). To me the "open loop gain A" is the gain of the amplifier without feedback (e.g. Ao in case of an opamp) and the "loop gain βAo" is the gain of the complete loop when it is opened at a suitable node.

Comment: @kile - I do not like the classification like "series-shunt" or "shunt-shunt" and so on....Therefore my answer to your question (first comment): It is voltage-controlled voltage feedback.

Comment: @LvW Can you have a look at my updated answer which I found from internet?

Comment: @LvW  βA is the open loop gain. It is used to plot the Nyquist diagram for studying the stability of the system. The loop can be cut at any point but the product  βA remains constant.

Comment: @LvW In systems theory, A indicates the gain of the direct action chain, while β indicates the gain of the feedback chain.

Comment: @Franc - sorry, but as to my knowledge most of the relevant literature is using the following notation: LOOP GAIN is the gain of the complete loop (βAo) when Ao is the gain of the circuit without feedback ("OPEN LOOP GAIN) and β is the feedback factor. I am aware that we are discussing nomenclature (semanthic) only - however, I consider such a thing as important in order to avoid misunderstandings. Regarding breaking the loop: I agree, that the loop can be cut at any point - however, only  under consideration of the loading effects. Therefore, some specific nodes are preferrable.

Comment: @LvW Can you have a look at my answer found from internet?

Answer (score 0):

The indicated text is aimed at those who know electronics and the principles of negative feedback well. The amplifier in question is indeed a feedback amplifier. There are four configurations of a feedback amplifier. The one in question falls into one of these. But without knowing the principles of the reaction one gets lost in more or less correct calculations.

Comment: How are you gonna solve this feedback problem?